# CodeIgniter3 - password hashing doesn't work for all special characters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, bcrypt

I'm trying to hash passwords using the CodeIgniter 3 library "Community Auth", and I think I've found that only certain special characters will work. I just can't tell why, or really what's happening to them.

- Here's an example password that works: KA83**8!d#
- Here's an example password that does **NOT** work: 1aA!@#%^&*()-_=+{};:,<.>

**Edit:** I should clarify that the passwords save to the DB, but trying to login is what doesn't work.

If I pull the below methods out to a single function that does hash_passwd and password_verify, then a comparison do work for both passwords.

Should I be using preg_quote on the string so that it saves correctly to the database? I tried, but it didn't seem to affect anything.

Here are the two methods that I use to change a password, and then the third to check for login.

**Model = application\models\User_model.php

Method = change_password**

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_data->user_id)
                    ->update(
                            $this->db_table('user_table'), [
                        'passwd' => $this->authentication->hash_passwd($password),
                        'passwd_recovery_code' => NULL,
                        'passwd_recovery_date' => NULL
                            ]
            );
```

**Model = application\third_party\community_auth\libraries\Authentication.php

Method = hash_passwd**

```
public function hash_passwd($password) {
    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 11]);
}
```

**Model = application\third_party\community_auth\libraries\Authentication.php

Method = check_passwd**

```
    public function check_passwd($hash, $password) {
    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The change_password method is escaping the password, but the login method was not.  Updated to escape both, and now it works.